# Print values from JS variable to div

Tags: javascript, html

How would I print the 'title' and 'firstname' values from this variable into a div?

```
var relationshipList = [
    { name: 'William Cotterll',           firstname: 'William',  title: 'EVP Solutions' },
    { name: 'Edwin Van Der Saar',         firstname: 'Edwin',  title: 'Security Specialist' },
    { name: 'Kelly Woodson',              firstname: 'Kelly',  title: 'Production Manager'},               
];
```

EDIT:

If I wanted to print out the 'firstname' value, when I already knew the 'title' value, how could I achieve that?

For example, I only want to print out firstname when the title == 'EVP Solutions'.

Comment: By manipulating the element (for example `.innerText` attribute). If the element doesn't exist yet, you need to create it first.

Comment: Loop over the array and use the `innerHTML` property of the div to append the values you want..

Comment: Iterate over the array using a loop. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I received -1 for some reason for asking a question,

I think I figured it out,

```
            var Chkr;
            Chkr = relationshipList;
            if(relChkr[1].title == 'EVP Solutions'){
                console.log(relChkr[1].name);
            }else{
                console.log('');
            };
```

Not perfect but I can throw it into a div now so is all good.

Comment: You got -1 at the time because you didn't show what you had attempted to do or what you were having a specific problem with.

Answer (score 1):

```
var toInsert = '';

for (var i = 0, l = relationshipList.length; i < l; i++) {
    toInsert += relationshipList[i].title + ' ';
    if( relationshipList[i].title == 'EVP Solutions'){
        toInsert += ', ' + relationshipList[i].firstname + ' ';
    }
}

document.getElementById('#yourDivId').innerHTML = toInsert;
```

EDIT: I've added functionality that you added in your edit

Comment: Depending on where the data comes from, you should apply proper escaping or use `textContent`

Comment: I just have one extra question Jimmy, please see above.