# If two elements do not exist, call function. JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I need to check if two elements exist, and if they BOTH don't, call a function.

This doesn't work. Anyone have any suggestions?

```
var one = $('.one span');
var two = $('.two span');
(one.length && two.length) ? console.log('') : thisFunc();
```

Comment: I don't know what `length` might be returning, but depending on the number, it could be interpreted as true or false (like 1 or 0). To check if they exist, did you try `!!one && !!two`? If they both exist, that should return true.

Comment: So what's the problem with comparing the respective lengths to `0`? You [already know how](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246855/print-values-from-js-variable-to-div/19248888#19248888) to use `==` to compare.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery selectors are returning an object. The object has a length. The length is a number. If there are no matches for that selector, the length will be `0`. Personally I would rather be explicit and use `length === 0`:

```
(one.length === 0  && two.length === 0) ? thisFunc() : console.log('');
```

This is self-documenting: If `one`'s length is `0` and `two`'s length is `0` then run your function.

Of course, `0` evaluates to `false` in a boolean context so you could do:

```
(!one.length && !two.length) ? thisFunc() : console.log('');
```

or

```
!(one.length || two.length) ? thisFunc() : console.log('');
```

If you prefer.

At the moment, the `false` side of your ternary operator will be evaluated if either *or* both of the two elements don't exist, because:

```
true && false === false
false && true === false
false && false === false
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, I appreciate the detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

Consider combining your selector.

```
var both = $('.one span, .two span');

if (!both.length)
    thisFunc();
```

This is both more readable and better performing because the document is iterated over only once.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've got your logic backwards. You're looking for the function to fire if `one.length` is 0 and `two.length` is 0. That means you want `!(one.length || two.length)`. So your example should read:

```
var one = $('.one span');
var two = $('.two span');
(one.length || two.length) ? console.log('') : thisFunc();
```

The way that the logical `not` operator affects conjunctions (`&&`) and disjunctions (`||`) is described by De Morgan's laws ([wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)). Basically, that says:

```
"not (A and B)" is the same as "(not A) or (not B)"
"not (A or B)" is the same as "(not A) and (not B)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer you're after is

```
var one = $('.one span');
var two = $('.two span');
(!one.length && !two.length) ? thisFunc() : console.log('')
```

If I understand your requirement, your logic is flawed because you log '' to the console if both have a length, otherwise you call your function - which will happen if *either* or *both* don't have a length

Answer (score 0):

Put a ! in front of it?

```
!(one.length && two.length) ? console.log('') : thisFunc();
```

Switch your ternary operands?

```
(one.length && two.length) ? thisFunc() : console.log('')
```

Demorgan's law?

```
!one.length || !two.length ? console.log('') : thisFunc();
```

Or did you mean to change the logic?

```
!(one.length || two.length) ? console.log('') : thisFunc();
```

In summary, I still don't know what you're talking about, and "BOTH" in caps did not clarify. One or several of these is probably what you want since I covered most things you can do.

Comment: [De Morgan's Law](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan's_laws) for anyone unfamiliar (or forgot, like me).

Comment: I don't know why this has any upvotes. None of them are the correct answer to the question. If the `true` and `false` parts of the bottom one were switched around, it would be correct...

Comment: @TomFenech if you understood the question then just answer it.

Comment: He answered it half an hour ago. Question seems pretty clear. If both do not exist, call a function.

Comment: @cookiemonster "if both do not exist" meaning, "if they don't both exist", or, "if neither exists"? that's why I just threw a bunch of boolean options out there, but, darn, missed the one OP actually wanted.

Comment: The phrasing in the question could have been a little cleaner.

Comment: Sorry all, I guess I could have explained it better.